# What is this transparent round "plate" brick with wiring inside?

Tags: part-identification

I bought a crate of Lego's from a flea market, and it has this strange block inside it. It's a transparent blue color, round, and somewhat thick. It seems to be a single piece, I can't find anywhere to separate it. It has wiring inside of an unknown purpose, and I can't see anywhere to connect to the wiring, so I am assuming it's some kind of wireless thing, but I can't imagine to what end. There are at least 3 of them that I have found so far, and they all have different numbers on them - `40R5`, `30R5`, `16R5`, and some smaller numbers that I couldn't quite make out. There is a shallow circle hole on the bottom, but it's just barely too small for a normal brick "dot" to fit into.

I'm curious what these are for, and what set they might have come with.

[image]

[image]

Comment: that's an RFID tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After posting, I was finally able to manipulate the image enough to get the right part number (or part of a part number) and found out that it is [18602c01](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18602c01#T=C). It's a generic gadget base. This base is part of a LEGO Dimensions video game which had different characters, and you could put the [unique base](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Dimensions%20Toy%20Tag#T=A) into a [Lego Dimensions Toy Pad](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Dimensions%20Toy%20Pad#T=A) that would detect which character it was (hence the wireless stuff inside). You could then play as that character in the video game.

<strike>I'm assuming the other larger lettering (`30R5`, etc) are designations indicating the character the base belongs to.</strike>

As pointed out by Alex in the comments, the `30R5` etc. codes are manufacture dates.

Comment: 30R5 - is a production week. In this case it is 30th week of 2015.

Comment: IIRC the wiring is a standard NFC tag, though it's been years since I've played with them so I might be remembering incorrectly.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, @Alex, thanks. I wonder how you are supposed to know which base goes to which gadget, once they are apart?

Comment: I remember scanning couple of these generic tags I got from Bricklink with smart phone only to find they are all the same. I haven't played the game, but it makes me thing generic tags/bases are somehow tied with character tag/base.

Comment: @NathanStohlmann Probably just RFID, which is admittedly kind of sort of a subset of NFC, but is a tad cheaper to implement.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn they use NFC. I just checked one tag/base with my phone. And it also says the tag is "writable" so, I guess, it can be reused for something else. I don't have any of character specific ones to check though.